# Failed to create a react native project

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to create a project with react native but my problem is when i run the order

```
create-react-native-app AwesomeProject
```

i get several errors

```
npm WARN deprecated istanbul-lib-hook@1.2.1: 1.2.0 should have been a major version bump
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...aps-1.0.0-alpha.4.tgz'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/pc/.npm/_logs/2018-06-27T14_25_11_764Z-debug.log
Failed to install
```

i tried many solutions but without success 
i have npm 6.1.0 and node 8.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow all of the instructions on the official `CRNA` page: https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app

Namely:

```
$ npm install -g create-react-native-app
$ create-react-native-app AwesomeProject
$ cd my-app/
$ npm start
```

Comment: yes, i followed it but without result, the first order worked but the problem apear at the second order

Comment: Have you tried to clean your cache? npm clean cache --force

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall Node, then restart your computer, then re-install Node?

Comment: i work with it because i have created the api so node it works good fo me